# Op-Amp Feedback Phase Shift

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

If we have the following differential op-amp:

[image]

Let's say that VB and VA are sine waves. VB is 180 degrees out of phase from VA. Now, we know that the op-amp output tries to make V+ equal V-. My question is, is V+ equal to V- only in magnitude or in phase too?

meaning, does the op-amp output make V+=V- only in magnitude or in phase too?
So, if I probe V+ and V-, should they be in phase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you operate within the conditions to approximate the op. amp as an ideal component \$V_+ = V_-\$. Period.

Meaning: at each instant in time both nodes have the same potential. Which also means they vary with the same amplitude, frequency, phase.

If you plot both signals with time, they will be identical for an ideal op. amp.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, is V+ equal to V- only in magnitude or in phase too?

To a very good approximation, V+ and V- are equal in both magnitude and phase.

However, if they were *precisely* equal, there would be no differential signal to amplify. Let's call the very small difference between V+ and V-, Verror. Because opamps have compensation, Verror is generally out of phase with Vout, often close to 90 degrees.

The following circuit simulation illustrates this nicely.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv5PtX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]